# How to do change of basis

Tags: matrices

As a beginner, I have read several examples related to the topic however still do not get the point. Would you please explain me with this particular case?
basis A=[a,b]
column*row
[a,b][a,b] gives matrix M in basis A=
{{aa,ab},{ba,bb}}
now with a new basis B= [x,y]
x=3a+b
y=2a+b

if we do matrix p=
3,1
2,1
and apply p m p-1 (as the book)

why the answer is not equal to
{{xx,xy},{yx,yy}}
?
(here xx=(3a+b)^2, and etc.)

And how to do it in the correct way?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: For this you will find this useful http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ncu9Pks3AJQ

Comment: can you write the math part a little bit clearer?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).